# TinyMCE popup window with list

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE editor in my custom CMS. I'd like to add a custom button on my toolbar on which when the user clicks, a window pops up with a list of elements. Then the user can select an element and by pressing the OK button the window closes and copies the text of the selected element into the textarea at the current position of the cursor. I have find lots of examples but neither of them worked. I'd like to ask some help.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having the same problem, I found this :

[how to add tinymce listbox values in windowmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602764/how-to-add-tinymce-listbox-values-in-windowmanager)

From the selected answer:

```
{type: 'listbox', 
    name: 'align', 
    label: 'align', 
    'values': [
        {text: 'Left', value: 'left'},
        {text: 'Right', value: 'right'},
        {text: 'Center', value: 'center'}
    ]
}
```

I hope this helped !